# MVC how to post serialized form data to controller?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm working through a tutorial on CRUD operations using modal partialview in ASP.NET MVC. It appears that the JQuery code is capturing the form elements and their values, but no data gets passed to the controller ("emp" contains null values). What am I doing wrong?

Here is the controller action:

[image]

Here is the modal view:

[image]

Here is the JQuery:

[image]

Finally, here is the alert showing what "sendData" contains prior to the post:

[image]

Using Serge's recommendation, the JQuery has been changed to:

```
<script>        

$(function () {

    var PlaceHolderElement = $('#PlaceHolderHere');

    PlaceHolderElement.on('click', '[data-save="modal"]', function (event) {
        var form = $(this).parents('.modal').find('form');            
        var actionUrl = form.attr('action');
        var sendData = form.serialize();

        $.ajax({
            url: actionUrl,
            type: "POST",
            data: sendData,
            contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
        });
        
    });
});
```

... and here is a screen capture of the debug session showing changes to controller method and argument values:

[image]

The Employee model:

```
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;

namespace modaldemo2.Models
{
   
    public class Employee
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the `Employee` class look like?

Comment: Would be better if you share your code as snippet, but not images.

Comment: @YongShun thanks for pointing that out. I will do that from now on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a bug in a sendData, it is becaue of  your view , remove name=".. " from your input controls, or as a work around try this

```
<input asp-for="Name" name="Name" class="form-control/>
....
<input asp-for="Email" name="Email" class="form-control/>
```

try to add [FromForm] to the action

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create ( [FromForm] Employee emp)
```

and it is better to this ajax syntax

```
 var sendData = form.serializeArray();

           $.ajax({
            url: actionUrl,
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
            data: sendData,
            success: function (result) {
            },
            error: function (xhr, exception) {
           }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks Serge, I change the JQuery to use ajax, and added [FromForm] to the controller method argument. Unfortunately results are still same. I will place the code changes into my original post.

Comment: @GPaw Try without [FromForm] , it depends on net version

Comment: @GPaw you have a bug in a sendData, it is becaue of  your view , remove name=".. " from your input controls

Comment: I removed name attributes from both input controls, tested, no change. Then also removed [FromForm], tested, no change.

Comment: @GPaw try sendData= form.serializeArray(); and let me know how senddata looks now

Comment: I get nothing. When I add the input name attributes back, I get (from alert): sendData: [object Object],[object Object]

Comment: @GPaw you should use alert(JSON.stringify(sendData));

Comment: @GPaw It is in my answer ,  you never use input name attributes with mvc

Comment: I hear you on the name attribute, but I'm just trying to get this little example working because I will need to use these techniques for a real project. I added json.stringify to the alert (w/o name attributes, and again, got an empty object. Added the name attributes back, and got this: sendData: [{"name":"txtNameId","value":"Benny Hen"},{"name":"txtEmailId","value":"bhen@comedy.com"}] - but still nothing at the controller

Comment: @GPaw  I don' t know why  you got an empty object, but as a workaround see my updated answer.

Comment: well, that did the trick. Making the input name attributes same as the asp-for attributes. Interesting. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @GPaw You  are welcome! Names of  javascript properties should be the same as c# model properties names. But I never used names explicetly, by default it should be the same names as Model property names., but for some reasons it doesnt' work in your case.